# How to display:none woocommerce variation price using jquery when variation select change?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I need hide woocommerce variation price when variation select change, but the code below doesn't work. Defaultly the price is showing after choosing any of the value from select and I need to achieve to stay the price hidden.

```
<script>
   jQuery("select").change(function() {
       jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-price").css("display","none");
   });
</script>
```

I updated the code to:

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
   jQuery("select").change(function() {
      jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-price").css("display","none");
   });
});
```

But it doesn't work. I tested it and console.log works, but any code do still nothing.

Comment: The variation price changes with ajax.  You need to wrap in `.on('ajaxComplete', yourFunction() )`

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply.
Should it be:?
`<script>
   jQuery("select").on("ajaxComplete", function() {
       jQuery(".woocommerce-variation-price").css("display","none");
   });
</script>`

This code doesn't work for me.